# The integral of $\int \frac{x^3}{4-\sqrt{x}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to get the integral of :
$$\int \frac{x^3}{4-\sqrt{x}} dx$$
I have tried the substitution $u=\sqrt x$

Comment: Maybe $u  =4 -\sqrt{x}$ might do better? (Note : if you make further progress on any tips mentioned in the comments, add them in the question post with the tag "edit")

Comment: the integration region has to avoid $x\le 0$ and $x=16$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This substitution might not give wanted results.

$I=\int \frac{x^{3}}{4-\sqrt{x}} dx\\
Let\ x=( t+4)^{2}\\
dx=2( t+4) dt\\
I=\int \frac{( t+4)^{6} \cdot 2( t+4)}{4-( t+4)} =-2\int \frac{( t+4)^{7}}{t} dt\\$

Use the binomial theorem to expand out the numerator, and then use standard intgration techniques to evaluate each individual expression in the expansion.